# How to hide collision shape lines in viewport?

Tags: collision

I don't know what I'm missing, it should be totally simple and I found nothing about how to hide the collision shapes in viewport.
(For some objects I chose a simple collision shape that doesn't necessarily fit the object shape)

[image]

Comment: There's no option in the Viewport Overlays panel so I guess you can't disable the shape display

Comment: @moonboots - thanks for clarifying it

Comment: It looks like it is not possible even with python. According to ChatGPT :) there is not an API to controlle visibility of collision_shape component. So the only one option seems to be disable all Overlays. As workaround I wanted to change Theme of 3Dviewport and set Alpha to zero, but there is only RGB.

Comment: @vklidu - is there a way to disable all overlays in the editor? I tried turning off everything but the wireframe of the collision shape stay.  That's really strange there is no toggle function for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible even with python. According to ChatGPT :) there is not an API to controlle visibility of collision_shape component.

As workaround I wanted to change *Theme* of *3D Viewport* and set *Alpha* to zero, but there is only RGB.

So the only one option seems to be hide all Overlays (gizmo, outlines, ...)

[image]